# How did Wolverine get his Adamantium claws back?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, the-wolverine

In "The Wolverine", during the final battle, the Silver Samurai heats up his sword and cuts off Wolverine's Adamantium claws:

Then, after the Silver Samurai has been injured, Wolverine grows back his original bone claws:

But, in "Days of Future Past", Wolverine has his Adamantium claws again.  There was no real explanation as to how he got them back, as he still had his bone claws at the end scene where Magneto and Charles Xavier come to see him.

**So what is the *in-universe* or *out-of-universe* explanation for Wolverine getting his Adamantium claws back?**

Comment: So based on your comments on the answer, are you asking how Wolverine, whose super power is to regenerate and grow back parts, grew back parts?

Comment: If so, it'd help if you added context, like that beforehand he'd had his healing powers drained. It's just unclear what you're asking and the adamantium part also confuses the issue.

Comment: @CreationEdge, I give up.

Comment: Related on M&TV: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/why-does-wolverine-still-have-adamantium-claws-in-x-men-days-of-future-past

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bryan Singer, **Magneto was involved**.

To quote directly from the [same question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/why-does-wolverine-still-have-adamantium-claws-in-x-men-days-of-future-past) on Movies & TV, which [quotes ScreenRant](http://screenrant.com/x-men-days-future-past-rogue-wolverine-metal-claws/), which, in turn, [quotes Empire](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/wolverine-metal-claws-x-men-days-future-past-explained/) (emphasis and crop mine):

> . . . Singer hinted at a possible explanation:
>
> Director Bryan Singer explains that Magneto’s ability to manipulate metal might have something to do with it. The Master Of Magnetism could, perhaps, “reconstitute the adamantium claws… [Wolverine] has a different relationship with Magneto, and **perhaps Magneto could forge them**.”

Since Magneto is *the master of magnetism*, we could make a logical leap here and assume that he manipulated Admantium in Wolverine's claws to reattach them, given of course that Wolverine had saved his detached claws from his fight with the Samurai.

I'd also like to point out that this explanation doesn't necessarily hold for the updated timeline. You know, in *Days of Future Past* where

> Raven fishes Logan from a river disguised as Col. Stryker.

Don't know what happened next, since I haven't watched *Apocalypse* yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely during the scene with Magneto and Xavier, you can see [in this clip](https://youtu.be/0ZkfyBAtUk4?t=39) that his claws no longer have adamantium on them (in case the timestamp doesn't work, the relevant portion starts at 0:39):

[image]

So, his healing factor allowed him to regenerate the bone of his claws, but the adamantium needs to be re-applied (the rest of his skeleton still has the adamantium).

Comment: I already pointed that out in my question and He has them in the next movie timeline.

Comment: @KyloRen So, your question is how did he get them back in _Days of Future Past?_  Because, your question only mentioned _The Wolverine,_ so I presumed that you didn't realize that he still had only bone claws at the end.

Comment: @KyloRen No, in your question you say that he grows back his _Adamantium_ claws, which he doesn't. He grows back his bone claws only, no Adamantium. You don't mention any other film in your question.

Comment: @CreationEdge no "he has them" as in has still has the bone claws. In the context that what it means